# MPI Genetic Monte Carlo Algorithm Resources?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, openmpi

I have been working with some friends to convert a Matlab Genetic Algorithm to C++ and it works in a sequential order currently.  Matlab is no longer a portion of our current code.

We are looking to use it on a cluster, but have been a little dry on resources.  We have a cluster available at the University and it is equipped with Rocks and OpenMPI, but I'm not really sure where to begin working with it.

We currently have 2D and 3D Arrays setup with the data in them and when the system is doing crossover or exchanging between the models it just tries swapping parts of the 2D and 3D array.  What are some good ways to separate these structures across multiple nodes?

Comment: I'm still looking for some online references for this problem.  Any ideas?  Are books the only way to go?  (tomorrow, to the library!)

Comment: A Google search of "parallel genetic algorithm" returns a number of excellent resources.  Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: We decided on our MPI call structure, but I'm still not completely sure about the calls to use to obtain that structure.  I found some resources online.  
http://sci.tamucc.edu/~mscherger/AOS/Notes/slides2.pdf
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi_advanced/DavidCronkSlides.pdf

Mostly the questions pertain to...  How do I send 2D and 3D structures between nodes?

Comment: Just found another resource stemming from PPT at TAMUCC. http://www.cs.uncc.edu/~abw/parallel/par_prog/index.htm  There is a book there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing matrix computations, then whether there's even a good way to partition the calculations is highly dependent upon the calculation itself.

I'd highly recommend the Golub and van Loan book, "Matrix Computations, 3rd Ed.".  In it there is an entire chapter devoted to parallel computations (Ch. 6).

OpenMPI is a fine middleware to use for this problem.  Since you're doing this in C++, you might also take a look at zeromq.  The two have different semantics, and one might favor your problem space or your skillset more than the other.

Also, you should know that parallel matrix computations (typically signal processing, but there are lots of other applications) is a very, very active area of research.

Comment: Are there any online resources you might recommend.  I will search using Parallel Matrix Computations... maybe this will turn up more than parallel genetic algorithm resources.

Comment: For math things, I almost always start with the books on my shelf or with mathworld.wolfram.com

Comment: Another resource that might be of use is the research group called Parasol in the computer science department at TAMU.  http://parasol.tamu.edu/index.php

They research a lot of parallel/distributed system concepts, and one of the things they've been working on since I was in school there is a parallelized STL.

Answer (score 0):

### Fitness Calculation:

You typically just need to know about one individual to calculate its fitness, so you can just work through the population by doling out individuals to each core.  When an individual's fitness has been calculated, hand that core a new individual.

### Crossover:

A divide and conquer approach might be well suited to this problem.  Break your arrays into blocks that are processed by each CPU core, then perhaps add a global crossover step (mating a subset of pairs) to ensure you have the ability to move through the multidimensional space appropriately.